# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm, heap-memory

I can't make any search with npm:

```
npm search material
```

..results with the following error:

```
npm WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I tried with the following command

```
npm --max_old_space_size=16384 search material
```

but I had the same result.

npm version is 3.10.3

Comment: I use to have a similar problem with a node script, I used those flags: `node --max_old_space_size=8192 --optimize_for_size --max_executable_size=4096 --stack_size=4096 .`. Hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 3):

According to npm's bug tracker, this has been fixed in npm@4.0.0. (see [thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12619)).

Searching works fine for me after [upgrading npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12619#issuecomment-261689262):

> npm install npm@latest -g

(you might need to su/sudo on your system)