# Font generation with webfont: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, svg, v8, heap-memory, webfonts

I run the [my script](https://github.com/parlr/Hanzi-Pinyin-Font/blob/9b7bd1c607f97c10c9b781e04a39404caac65873/index.js#L29-L38) that use [`webfont`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfont) on a directory with `41214` SVG files and got the following error

````
function buildFont(config) {
  return webfont({
    files: config.inputFiles,
    fontName: config.fontName
  })
    .then(content => content)
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```
````

#### Error

```
node --require babel-core/register ./index.js
already exists                                 

<--- Last few GCs --->                         

  232006 ms: Mark-sweep 1350.0 (1406.9) -> 1349.8 (1406.9) MB, 574.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  232583 ms: Mark-sweep 1349.8 (1406.9) -> 1349.8 (1406.9) MB, 576.6 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  233164 ms: Mark-sweep 1349.8 (1406.9) -> 1349.8 (1403.9) MB, 580.3 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  233745 ms: Mark-sweep 1349.8 (1403.9) -> 1349.7 (1403.9) MB, 580.3 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->                        

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    2: arguments adaptor frame: 2->1           
Security context: 0x4e54c9cfb39 <JS Object>    
    3: round [/data/projects/hanzi-pinyin-font/node_modules/svg-pathdata/src/SVGPathData.js:12] [pc=0x26e3767b3b09] (this=0x217c839e5e99 <an SVGPathData with map 0x375d0749d7b1>)                                 
    4: arguments adaptor frame: 1->0           
    5: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [/data/projects/hanzi-pinyin-font/node_modules/svgicons2svgfont/src/index.js:336] [pc=0x26e376698166]...                                                               

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]                       
 2: 0x109b1dc [node]                           
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 6: v8::internal::DeoptimizationOutputData::New(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node] [node]
 7: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::PopulateDeoptimizationData(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Code>) [node]
 8: v8::internal::FullCodeGenerator::MakeCode(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [node]
 9: v8::internal::Compiler::EnsureDeoptimizationSupport(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [node]
10: 0xb538d7 [node]                            
11: 0xb54d4d [node]                            
12: v8::internal::Compiler::CompileOptimized(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ConcurrencyMode) [node]                                                                       
13: v8::internal::Runtime_CompileOptimized_Concurrent(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
14: 0x26e374e092a7                             
Aborted                                        
error Command failed with exit code 134.
```

#### Question

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[@evilebottnawi says](https://github.com/itgalaxy/webfont/issues/54#issuecomment-289753847):

> @edouard-lopez due to the large number of files node exceeded the limit memory (`512mb`) default. You can try increase memory, see http://prestonparry.com/articles/IncreaseNodeJSMemorySize/

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to NPM@4 is another solution (cf. [FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38914471/802365))

```
nvm use 7.7.4
fnm 7.7.4
```