# Ionic3 android build command not working - FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

My ionic 3 application working fine in Ionic serve , But when taking build it’s keep on stops with the following error

```
==== JS stack trace =========================================
Security context: 000000200D3CFB49 <JS Object>
    1: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [native array.js:~129] [pc=00000315AEFE6C02] (this=000000200D304381 <undefined>,w=000000FF69DCAE69 <JS Array[414]>,x=414,N=000000200D3043C1 <true>,J=000000200D3AE4C9 <String[1]:  >,I=000000200D3B46D9 <JS Function ConvertToString (SharedFunctionInfo 000000200D352DC9)>)
2: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:180] [pc=00000315AEFFA292] (this=000000200D304381 <undefined>...

 FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

**And My ionic info**

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
  ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3

global packages:

  Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

  @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
  Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1

System:

  Android SDK Tools : 24.4.1
  Node              : v6.10.3
  npm               : 3.10.10
  OS                : Windows 7
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL ERROR: CALL\_AND\_RETRY\_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914471/fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-javascript-heap-out-of-memo)

Comment: Why don't you try latest Ionic 3.7.1 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases/tag/v3.7.1

Comment: upgraded ionic, still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have fixed the issue with these steps :***

1. Add  **"C:\Windows\System32"** in Environment Environment variable Path .
2. Remove Platform by **ionic cordova platform rm android**
3. Add Platform using cordova by **cordova platform add android**
4. Take build by **ionic cordova run android**
5. Check generated Apk in your project , **Ex : D:\Ionic3\testify\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk**

I hope this is a problem caused by latest ionic version , Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I updated the build scripts in package.json and it worked.

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "node --max-old-space-size=2048 ./node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "node --max-old-space-size=2048 ./node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
```